# Dropbox v2 SDK Dot Net Delete Shared link

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk

I am using VS2013 Winforms and Dropbox SDK version 5.5.0 for Dot Net and trying to "delete" or "unshare" the shared public link created earlier with this code but it is not working.

Await dbx.Sharing.UnshareFileAsync("FilePath")

It throws an exception > "Error in call to API function "sharing/unshare_file": Your API app is an "App Folder" app. It is not allowed to access this API function"
Any ideas why is it so and how to delete the public shared link.

Comment: Please edit your post to contain a minimal, repoducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `UnshareFileAsync` method](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Sharing_Routes_SharingUserRoutes_UnshareFileAsync_1.htm) is for unsharing a specifically shared file, not for deleting a shared link. (These are different features.) Per the error message, this method is not supported for apps using [the "app folder" access type](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/developer-guide#app-permissions), so your app cannot call it.

If you want to revoke a shared link, you should instead use [`RevokeSharedLinkAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Sharing_Routes_SharingUserRoutes_RevokeSharedLinkAsync_1.htm).

Comment: Thanks Greg. It does work for my specific case - all files are either PDF or Jpeg but with Excel, on Creating shared link (CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync) there is a problem on the permission. The requested visibility changes to Team only and  Public, but the link permissions change to Team only and Access level to Editor where as before "recreating " shared link, the requested visibility was Public and Access Level as Nothing.

Comment: It sounds like you're running in to a different issue, so please open a new post with the details.